# Access multilevel v-model from HTML (Nested element)

Tags: javascript, html, django, vue.js

The `HTML` code is here

```
<section id="id_element">

    <label for="x1">x1 </label>
    <input type="text" id="x1"  v-model="product.xs.x1" ></input>

    <label for="x2">x2</label>
    <input type="text" id="x2"  v-model="product.xs.x2" ></input>

</section>
```

here is my `javascript` :

```
<script>
const create = Vue.createApp({
        delimiters: ['[[', ']]'],
        data() {
            return {
                product : {
                    xs: {
                        "x1" : "alpha",
                        "x2" : "beta"
                    },
                    ys: {
                        "y1": "one",
                        "y2": "two",
                        "y3": "three",
                        "y4": "four"
    
                    }            
                }
    
            }
        }
        create.mount("#id_element");
</script>
```

I want to access a nested element, but i had the error of

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'x1')
```

how to access a multi level `vue.js` element from `HTML`.

I tried both :

```
v-model="product.xs["x1"]"
```

and

```
v-model="product.xs.x1"
```

So please anyone having a solution for this, it will be great.

Comment: The error says `Uncaught (in promise)`, but there is no promise in the given code. Do you use `x1` somewhere else?

Comment: @MoritzRingler yes, I do it in other inputs, and use it in a function.

Comment: Then that is where the error occurs. The statement `v-model="product.xs.x1"` is fine, I don't see how it could cause the issue. If you add that code to the question, it should be easy to figure out.